# Creating a simple facebook page tab

Tags: facebook

What happend to the good old page tab?
How can I create  a simple page tab and show some individual content from my website?
Even the original facebook docs seems to be not up to date: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs

I already created an facebook app and managed to show my own content. But I have no idea how to move that "app" into my facebook page as a tab.

Can anybody help me getting started and create a simple page tab?

Comment: Have you even read the document you linked to? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs#adding

Answer (score 0):

It's in the docs, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs/#Creating

You have to do a `POST /{page_id}/tabs` with the outlined fields, as in the docs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
This worked for me and my app is running now. But for some reason I cannot add the app to a fanpage, I always get the error message: "This app cannot be integrated into your profil".
So overall the app is done but i cannot integrate it into any page.

Comment: What does "it is working now" exaclty mean? Also, what means "a fanpage"? A page you do not have admin privileges to?